# Force typescript to respect class types

Tags: typescript

I've this code:

```
class A {
    public var1: string = 'var1';
}

class B {
    public var1: string = 'var1';
    public var2: string = 'var2';
}

const instance: A = new B();
console.log(instance instanceof A);
```

I don't undestand why typescript compilator is OK with `instance: A = new B()` because B don't extends A. If A and B was Interface i understand because interfaces aren't kept on execution, but for Class i don't understand.

And the last line return "false" so it's the proof that A isn't B!

There is a thing to do it? Compilator option? Code with Generics?...

Regards.

Comment: `B` is not an instance of `A`, it merely shares a common property `var1`. You have to derive from it then so they have that inheritance relation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why typescript is not showing you any error when you did `const instance : A = new B()` is because typescript uses structural typing, so basically, if the structure/shape conforms to one another, typescript is okay with this.

For example if we have something like this

```js
class A {
  foo() : boolean { return true }
}

class B {
 foo() : boolean { return true }
}

const bar : A = new B()
```

The typescript compiler sees the above as the same thing because of the structure, but as soon as you change the structure, it will be flagged by the compiler.

```js
class AA {
  foo() : boolean { return true }
}

class BB {
 foo() : string { return "true" }
}

const foobar : AA = new BB()
```

You will see this sort of error from tsc `Type 'BB' is not assignable to type 'AA'. The types returned by 'foo()' are incompatible between these types. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`

Back to your example `B` has the exact structure of `A` because `public var1: string` is present in both `B` and `A`, so `B` can be assigned to `A`, but when you flip it the other way around,

`const instance: B = new A()`

the compiler will flag the code, because `A` does not completely conform with the structure of `B` because  `public var2: string` is present in `B` and not in `A`.

In C++, Java, and few other languages that use nominal typing, the sort of code will be flagged by the compiler.

Comment: Yes i know it, but only for interfaces :(. There is no way to force Typescript to refuse assignation of B into A??